# Graph Partitioning Node Seperator

Tags: graph

I have a graph, and I have to partition this graph by removing some nodes, which means graph separator is node. What I am supposed to do is to minimize number of nodes which I will remove to separate the graph. In other words, with minimum number of nodes, I have to separate the graph into two components.

How can I do this ? At first I consider `Karger Algorithm`,but it does not guarantee minimization, and it is based on edge separator.